Line in Matlab plot do not appear
I am self studying Matlab and I want to create a plot with electron concentration and inverse temperature as the picture shows:

I have created a code in matlab but I do not see the line in the plot .Why ?
% Constants
k = 1.38e-23;  % Boltzmann's constant (J/K)
Eg = 1.12;     % Energy band gap of silicon (eV)
A = 2.5e19;    % Constant for intrinsic carrier concentration calculation
Nc = 2.8e19;   % Effective density of states in conduction band (cm^-3)
Nd = 1e16;     % Doping concentration (cm^-3)

% Temperature range
T = linspace(100, 1000, 100);  % Temperature range from 100 K to 1000 K

% Electron concentration for n-type doping
n = (Nc * Nv)^0.5 * exp(-Eg./(2*k*T));

% Calculate ln(n)
ln_n = log(n);

% Calculate 1/T
inv_T = 1 ./ T;

% Plot
plot(inv_T, ln_n, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('1/T');
ylabel('ln(N_D)');
title('ln(Electron Concentration) vs. 1/T for Silicon');
grid on;


Does anyone knows  ?

You can plot it as follows:
k = 1.38e-23;  % Boltzmann's constant (J/K)
k = 8.6173303e-5; % Boltzmann's constant (eV/K)
Eg = 1.12;     % Energy band gap of silicon (eV)
A = 2.5e19;    % Constant for intrinsic carrier concentration calculation
Nc = 2.8e19;   % Effective density of states in conduction band (cm^-3)
Nd = 1e16;     % Doping concentration (cm^-3)

% Temperature range
T = linspace(100, 1000, 100);  % Temperature range from 100 K to 1000 K

% Electron concentration for n-type doping
n = (Nc * Nd)^0.5 * exp(-Eg./(2*k*T));

% Calculate ln(n)
ln_n = log(n);

% Calculate 1/T
inv_T = 1 ./ T;

% Plot
plot(inv_T, ln_n, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('1/T');
ylabel('ln(N_D)');
title('ln(Electron Concentration) vs. 1/T for Silicon');
grid on;

Your plot did not show up because the value is just too small, i.e., zero. You need to use k in the unit of eV. You also need to replace Nv as Nd. Attached is the plot of the intrinsic slope, after changing these two things.


Thank you very much.I didn’t notice that.But your solution graph is not the same as the picture in the OP.What modifications must be done in order to look like this?

@HomerJaySimpson i think n = (Nc * Nd)^0.5 * exp(-Eg./(2*k*T)); is not quite correct. It is supposed to be for the intrinsic part only. You need to update it with the correct equation to show the full picture.

it is a n-type semiconductor.Actually the line is splitted into 3 parts as the graph in OP suggests.
